# What issue exists when multiple lines of 'date' are used in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm currently reading through a book on bash programming, Pro Bash Programming. At one chapter (Chapter 4) they ask what problem the following script has. I myself have no clue after reading through. I must be missing something here. Can anyone show me what the issue here is?

```
year=$( date +%Y )
month=$( date +%m )
day=$( date +%d )
hour=$( date +%H )
minute=$( date +%M )
second=$( date +%S )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you're running these commands on Dec 31 at 23:59:59, and the clock ticks to the next second after, say, you get the month?

Safer:

```
read year month day hour minute second < <( date "+%Y %m %d %H %M %S" )
```

Be careful if you're using those value to do arithmetic: the shell considers `08` and `09` to be invalid octal numbers, not valid decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't this there is a real *error* in the script. But it is quite possible that, when reading all the string separately, you finally read a 
'second' value which does not correspond to the 'minute' before that, because it already changed...

Comment: How is that not a real *error*? It produces the *wrong* answer.

Comment: I meant that this would not cause an error message from the operating system. This is a programming error, not a system error...

Comment: Since the question asks for a "problem", I think getting the wrong answer counts. In fact, sometimes getting the wrong answer is *more* problematic than always getting an error message, since you might not fix it until after the shuttle disaster.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that it unsafely assumes all 6 calls to `date` are going to execute on the same wall-clock second. Imagine what might happen if the script gets to the first line around 2015-12-31 23:59:59.999 (plus or minus a few microseconds)?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to know this book. Read on to chapter 9 and you will find a section on setting multiple variables from a single command. There they will give an explanation, what's going on here.

In a gist it's a) inefficient (calling date is rather expensive), and b) risky, for the reasons given by jcoppens.